# Why is the text im typing not showing up in the texterea box?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to work though the markdown previewer, not yet at the hard but but im already stuck. Why is the textarea not showing the updated text im typing?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: ''
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState(state => {
      input: event.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <body>
        <div class="body-div">
          <form>
            <textarea
              class="editor"
              id="editor"
              placeholder="Type your code here..."
              value={this.state.input} onChange={this.handleChange}
             >{this.state.input}</textarea>
            <div id="preview" class="preview">
              <h1></h1>
              <h2></h2>
              <a></a>
              <script></script>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </body>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("target"));
```

I'm trying to work though the markdown previewer, not yet at the hard but but im already stuck. Why is the textarea not showing the updated text im typing?

Comment: Oh snap yeah it totally did, forgot to come back and say thanks! Also thanks for the className reminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the state value wrong. It should be:

```
this.setState({
          input: event.target.value
        });
```

And as a side note, you are supposed to use `className` instead of `class` in React.js.

So the code looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: ""
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState({
      input: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <body>
        <div className="body-div">
          <form>
            <textarea
              className="editor"
              id="editor"
              placeholder="Type your code here..."
              value={this.state.input}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            >
              {this.state.input}
            </textarea>
            <div id="preview" className="preview">
              <h1>{this.state.input}</h1>
              <h2>{this.state.input}</h2>
              <a>{this.state.input}</a>
              <script></script>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </body>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Live demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/setstate-class-l32m2u

Comment: Thank you! weird thing is i could have sworn i had it like this before and changed it because it wasnt working and i thought it was wrong

Answer (score 1):

Update the `handleChange` function like this:

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({
    input: event.target.value
  });
}
```

And set the value in the value attribute and remove it from inside the element like this:

```
<textarea
  class="editor"
  id="editor"
  placeholder="..."
  value={this.state.input} onChange={this.handleChange}>
</textarea>
```